# How to get list instead of object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, stdin

Excuse me.
This is a piece of code that is related to the input in the begging part.
can anyone help me find out how to get  lines=[] as a list?
since, after the stdin, I need to use this lines=[] as an input to the rest of the whole code.

could I get the type of list directly from this piece of code?
or is there any method to change it into a list from an object?

thx a lot in advance.

code :

---

```
let lines=[];

console.log(typeof(lines));


// function readinput(liness) {
//         liness = liness;
        
        let reader = require("readline").createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout,
        });
        

        reader.on('line', (line) => {
            // liness.push(line);
            // push(lines,line);
            lines.push(line);
        });

        reader.on('close', () => {　//受け取ったデータを用いて処理を行う
        console.log(lines);
            }
        )
    // }
```

---

result:
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Programming\A60question MapRoute\A45bighouse> node test.js
object
[]
object

2344 4543
245 335  56
4 56 5

[ '', '2344 4543 ', '245 335  56 ', '4 56 5', '' ]

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, an `Array` is a type of object. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array :

> In JavaScript, arrays aren't primitives but are instead Array objects

To verify that the `lines` object is indeed an `Array`, use `Array.isArray(lines)`. It should return `true` for your `lines` variable.